# Python Openpyxl Looping to modify specific value

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm having a problem with looping and editing specific cell values using Openpyxl. It would find the value but it won't edit the found value.

Thank you guys!

Here is my code:

```
xls = openpyxl.load_workbook(str(package_path))

BacNet_Device = xls[str(site_name) + ' BACnet Objects']

for row in BacNet_Device.values:
    for value in row:
        if value == "Please Fill Out":
            value = "N/A"
```

Comment: `BacNet_Device.values` is a tuple of the values in the worksheet. If you want to edit the worksheet you will need to assign the value for the relevant cell or cells. This is covered in the openpyxl documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the cell to update;

```
for row in BacNet_Device.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "Please Fill Out":
            BacNet_Device[cell.coordinate] = 'N/A'
```